# What does clear button set UITextField to?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a piece of code that's reacting to a text field being typed in.  I want to check when the `.text` of the field is empty (either backspaced all the way or cleared with the little round X button on the right).

If I check for `.text == @""` my code works provided the user backspaced.  It does not work if the user used the clear button.

What does the clear button set the text field's `.text` to?  (I've logged it out and it looks blank to me if I print it between two other characters.)

Perhaps I need to check for more than just `.text == @""`?  Perhaps `.length == 0` or something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "clear" button probably sets the `text` property to `nil`.

The best check whenever you wish to see if text is empty is to use:

```
if (someText.length == 0) {
    // soneText has no text (or someText is nil)
}
```

This works for empty strings as well as `nil` values.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm going to try this instead.